# Get only one column and create an alias for that column using "with()" function in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have two tables, `JobOrder` and `Job`. I'm using one-to-many relationship.

One `Job` can have many `JobOrder` and one `JobOrder` belongs to only one `Job`.

**JobOrder Model:**

```
public function job()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Job::class);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
public function getAllJobOrder()
{
    $results = JobOrder::with('job')->get();
    return $results;
}
```

the code above returns data like this:

[image]

I want to get only the `job->position` and create an alias just like this:
[image]

I can actually achieve the return in the above image using `withCount` but I don't think it is the right way to do it.

```
public function getAllJobOrder()
{
    $results = JobOrder::withCount(['job AS position' => function ($q) {
            $q->select('position');
        }])->get();
    return $results;
}
```

Is there any other way than using `withCount`?

Comment: If you want to always select single column then add select('position') with your relationship.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, using `select` requires the `id` column. which means it would return 2 columns.

Comment: Yes you are right. need id column always.

Comment: well I only need 1 column and not return a nested array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

**controller**

```
public function getAllJobOrder()
{
    $results = JobOrder::with('job')->get();
    foreach($results as $result){
       $result->position = $result->job->position;
       unset($result->job);
    } 
    return $results;
}
```